# The equivalent of `this` when using $(document).on('click', '.some-class',

Tags: jquery

When I'm using

`$(document).on('click', '.some-class',...`)

to call a function, what syntax do I use to refer to the `.some-class` element? `this` will grab the `document` instead of the actual element.

I have to use

`$(document).on('click', '.some-class',...`) instead of `$(..some-class').click()` because `.some-class` is created dynamically after page load.

Any help?

Comment: `$(event.target)`

Comment: `this` does not refer to document in that case: https://jsfiddle.net/ks85decc/ Please show a full example where `this === document`.

Comment: agree with @JJJ in your case also `this` refer to your `class element` not the `document`.

Comment: Jack Vawdrey   `this` will work perfectly fine in your case

Comment: Thanks, my mistake, it was in fact selecting the correct element, there was just a missing piece of the code. Thanks everyone!